# Installing Windows Features on remote server 2012 using powershell 3.0

Tags: powershell, powershell-3.0, powershell-remoting, powershell-ise

I am wondering which is **best practice** considering both examples will probably work. Using the built in help examples I have written a script to install windows features on remote servers. Here is my code:

```
$servers = ('server1', 'server2', 'server3', 'server4')

ForEach ($server in $servers) {
    Install-WindowsFeature -Name Desktop-Experience -ComputerName $server -IncludeAllSubFeature -IncludeManagementTools -Restart
}
```

Would the above be preferred OR should I wrap the "Install-WindowsFeature ..." in an "Invoke-Command" block like the following?

```
Invoke-Command -ComputerName server1, server2, server3, server4 -command {
    Install-WindowsFeature -Name Desktop-Experience -ComputerName $server -IncludeAllSubFeature -IncludeManagementTools -Restart
}
```

Thanks for your insight!

Answer (score 0):

Personally I would use the latter (directly call `Install-WindowsFeature -ComputerName $server` rather than do a separate `Invoke-Command`) *in this case* for the following reasons:

1. You may be hard-coding the feature names now, but in the future you may want to put those in a variable. If you put them in a variable, you'll have to pass it as a parameter into the `Invoke-Command`'s script block. This is entirely possible, but more work.
2. By using your own loop, you can write progress messages, logging, etc.
3. You gain nothing by using `Invoke-Command` in this case because you're running a single command on the remote computer (as opposed to running multiple commands with `-ComputerName` parameters vs. running multiple commands inside the script block).